# Reusing an HTML5 Audio object for repeated playing of the same mp3 sound effect

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome, audio, html5-audio

In a simple HTML5/WebGL app, I want to play a sound effect occasionally.

Currently I have in a constructor:

```
this.audio = new Audio('audio/zeep.mp3');
```

Then later, I want to play the file:

```
this.audio.play();
```

It works the first time, but second plays fail. I've tried resetting the `currentTime` to zero, and also to 0.1. Neither work:

```
this.audio.currentTime = 0;
this.audio.play();
```

If I recreate the `Audio` object with each time I want to play it, Chrome's network tab shows that it's going across the wire to re-fetch the file, rather than serving it from the cache.

Note that I don't need the same sound effect to play multiple times concurrently. This sound will be infrequent.

Am I missing something here?

Comment: Could you share an example of this happening? Maybe you are trying to play after something has invalidated the audio state. Otherwise, this should be working just fine... you can see (hear) a simple loop calling `play` every time the audio ends [here](http://jsfiddle.net/jbalsas/Ds9CF/)

Comment: @Jbalsas, that was the behaviour I expected too. Perhaps it was something specific to the MP3 file I was playing. Hopefully I'll have time to investigate further at some point soon.

Comment: what happens if u pause() , set currentTime & play()?

Answer (score 1):

## audio element Can't play again.

the http header of the audio file need to have **Content-Range** like:

`Content-Range:bytes 0-5151/5152`

it's designed for seeking.

and one audio element can NOT be playing concurrently, if need concurrency.use:

`var copy = audio.cloneNode();
copy.play();`